# Python: understanding difference between append and extend

Tags: python, list, append, extend

The code below will not run in its current state. However, if I change `sum_vec.extend( vec1[i] + vec2[i] )` to `sum_vec.append( vec1[i] + vec2[i] )` it works just fine. I understand the basic different between append and extend, but I don't understand why the code doesn't work if I use extend.

```
def addVectors(v1, v2):

    vec1 = list(v1)
    vec2 = list(v2)
    sum_vec = []
    vec1_len = len(vec1)
    vec2_len = len(vec2)
    min_len = min( vec1_len, vec2_len )

    # adding up elements pointwise
    if vec1_len == 0 and vec2_len == 0:
        return sum_vec
    else:
        for i in xrange(0, min_len):
            sum_vec.extend( vec1[i] + vec2[i] )

    # in case one vector is longer than the other
    if vec1_len != vec2_len:
        if vec1_len > vec2_len:
            sum_vec.extend( vec1[min_len : vec1_len] )
        else:
            sum_vec.extend( vec2[min_len : vec2_len] ) 
    print sum_vec
    return sum_vec

v1 = [1,3,5]
v2 = [2,4,6,8,10]
addVectors(v1,v2)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the difference between the versions of `sum_vec` after the two operations? What exactly does *"doesn't work"* mean - errors? Unexpected outputs?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `extend` takes an iterable (such as a list, tuple or string), and adds each element of the iterable to the list one at a time, while `append` adds its argument to the end of the list as a single item. The key thing to note is that `extend` is a more efficient version of calling `append` multiple times.

```
a = [1,2]
b = [1,2]

a.extend([3, 4])
for x in [3, 4]:
    b.append(x)

assert a == b
```

`append` can take an iterable as its argument, but it treats it as a single object:

```
a = [1,2]
a.append([3,4])
assert a == [1, 2, [3, 4]]  # not [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Why does python treat a string as a list when you do `a.extend(str)` ?

Comment: It doesn't treat it as a list; it treats it as an *iterable*, which is anything you can iterate over. You iterate over a string by getting its individual characters one by one. You iterate over a list or a tuple by getting its elements one by one. You iterate over a dict by getting its keys one by one. `extend` doesn't care *what* its argument is, as long as it can be iterated over.

Answer (score 5):

You can read the documentation on [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

`list.append` adds a single item to the end of your list:

> Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].

`list.extend` uses an iterable and adds all of it's elements to the end of your list:

> Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = L.

You need to use:

```
sum_vec.extend([vec1[i] + vec2[i]]) # note that a list is created
```

That way an iterable with a single item (`vec1[i] + vec2[i]`) is passed. But `list.append` is more suitable when you're always adding a single item.

Answer (score 5):

When you run your code, you get an exception like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../stack.py", line 28, in <module>
    addVectors(v1,v2)
  File ".../stack.py", line 15, in addVectors
    sum_vec.extend( vec1[i] + vec2[i] )
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

In other words, the [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method expects an iterable as argument.
However append method gets an item as argument.

Here is a small example of the difference between extend and append:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
m = [10, 11]
r = list(m)
m.append(l)
r.extend(l)

print(m)
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[10, 11, [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

The method append adds its parameter as a single element to the list, while extend gets a list and adds its content.

```
letters = ['a', 'b']

letters.extend(['c', 'd'])
print(letters)    # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

letters.append(['e', 'f'])
print(letters)    # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['e', 'f']]

names = ['Foo', 'Bar']
names.append('Baz')
print(names)   # ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']

names.extend('Moo')
print(names)   # ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'M', 'o', 'o']
```

Answer (score 1):

extend needs an iterable as a parameter
if you want to extend list by a single element you need to dress is in a list

```
a = []
b = 1

a.extend([b])
a.append(b)
```